# jQuery tab - need link to tab with (open the clicked Tab)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

Hope someone can help me getting this to work. Trying to make a working conection to tab. Link to tab is working but it doesent open the tab when click on Button.

TOP Navigation (Need to be Linked to Tab and open the clicked tab)...

```
        <nav class="primary">
      <a class="menu-select" href="#">menu</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">1p</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab1">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


                <div id="wrapper_tab" class="tab1">
                <a href="#tab1" id="tab1" class="tab1 tab_link">Tab 1</a>
                <a href="#tab2" id="tab2" class="tab2 tab_link">Tab 2</a>
                <a href="#tab3" id="tab3" class="tab3 tab_link">Tab 3</a>

                <div class="tab1 tab_body">
                    Some Text in Here
                </div>
                <div class="tab2 tab_body">
                    Some Text in Here
                </div>
                <div class="tab3 tab_body">
                    Some Text in Here
                </div>
                </div>
```

// Js

```
$(function() {
$('#wrapper_tab a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class') != $('#wrapper_tab').attr('class') ) {
        $('#wrapper_tab').attr('class',$(this).attr('class'));
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

Hope Someone can Help me with this problem.

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have no restrictions by the page weight - I suggest to use jquery ui tabs. About your code: You should not work with classes using attr method. Use methods from this page: http://api.jquery.com/category/css/

I found jsfiddle with simple tabs on pure jquery (without jquery ui) http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/Us8uc/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: is there nothing els i can do with javascrip ?? I am trying to keep it simple minimal jqery or scripts. Aktually it jumps down with the above code, but dont switch the tap with the jump down :( Hope anyone can help.

Comment: If You want to get working tabs fast - use jquery ui. If You want implement tabs yourself - do it. Your idea with classes is interesting, but you should use .addClass, .removeClass and hasClass methods instead of attr.

Comment: I can´t use jqueryUI for this projekt. So i must try this way. Litte bit javascript is ok. Thank u i will try this.

Comment: How can i prevent this from jumping to top of page when i include this tabbed content...??   http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/Us8uc/

Comment: Don't see any jumping. But event.preventDefault(); should prevent it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/93/ here jumping is reduced. And there will no jumping if all tabs will have same height.

Comment: i also use this tab. it nice and small script. i want to how can make auto change one by one. say like each 5 sec next tab will active. something like slider